# Need to reload many times to see correctly angular html component

Tags: html, angular

I'm using a template in my project. Before loging the page is configured to redirect in to a /threads all the methods that use is calling but is not showing in the page.

[image]

I need to refresh at least 3 times to show it correctly.
[image]

And the console error
[image]

On my component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
            this.filters = {
              id: '',
              title: '',
              description: '',
              category: '',
              initialDate: '',
              finalDate: '',
              status: 'Abierto',
              user: ''
            }
        
            this.term = '';
            // Get threads by filter
            this.getThreads(this.filters);           
          }


     // Get
      private getThreads(filters: any) {
        this.threadService.getByFilters(filters).subscribe(threads => {
          this.threads = this.filteredThreads = threads;
          this.threads.forEach(thread => thread.isSelected = false);
        });
      }
```

on my component.html

```
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" *ngFor="let header of headers" (click)="setSortingOptions(header)">
                                    <span class="sortable" *ngIf="header.toLowerCase() === this.sortHeader">
                                        <i
                                            [ngClass]="this.isFlowReverse  ? 'ti-arrow-circle-down' : 'ti-arrow-circle-up'"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="sortable">
                                        {{header}}
                                    </span>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let thread of filteredThreads  | orderBy: this.sortHeader : this.isFlowReverse: true | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize"
                                (click)="preview(thread)" [ngClass]="thread.isSelected ? 'selected': ''   ">
                                <td>
                                    <ngb-highlight [result]="thread.status" [term]="term"></ngb-highlight>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <ngb-highlight [result]="thread.title" [term]="term"></ngb-highlight>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <ngb-highlight [result]="thread.category" [term]="term"></ngb-highlight>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <ngb-highlight [result]="thread.date" [term]="term"></ngb-highlight>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <ngb-highlight [result]="thread.user" [term]="term"></ngb-highlight>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: You have a console error. Can you show that error in the first screenshot?

Comment: I'm not using ng-zorro-antd

Comment: That must be the way API response handled and rendered. Can you share some more details of code.

Comment: 1st thing: avoid `subscribe` inside `subscribe`. 2nd thing: display some loading message (at least in the console) while data are loading, you'll probably understand better what's going on

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557